# Magento Community - Coupon Code Functionality

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

Trying to create a coupon - $10 off min $150 excluding products from categories A, B, and C. But somehow can't get it to work. Have an instance whereby products from other categories (not A/B/C) amounted to $120, and a product from category A brought the total to above $150, and the coupon code still worked, when it is not supposed to work.

Input these in conditions:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total amount  equals or greater than  150  for a subselection of items in cart matching ANY  of these conditions:
Category  is not  244
Category  is not  535
Category  is not  576

Input this in actions:

Fixed amount discount for whole cart
Discount amount 10

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items):
Nothing inputted.

Even tried but to no avail
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total amount  equals or greater than  150  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
Category  is not one of 244,535,576

But somehow this is not working. Could anyone please advise?

Comment: The condition "category is not one of A,B,C" seems to be correct, but please make sure the product is not assigned to multiple categories ( i think it is the case)

Comment: Just realized what's wrong! Basically the coupon code did not take into account the different sizes of my configurable products. Meaning the parent product had a category, but as it is a configurable product, it's different sizes (which are products themselves) did not belong to any category. Hence it was excluded from the coupon code. Hope that helps anyone else with this problem!!

Comment: Please add your comments as an answer and mark your answer as "accepted" to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just realized what's wrong! Basically the coupon code did not take into account the different sizes of my configurable products. Meaning the parent product had a category, but as it is a configurable product, it's different sizes (which are products themselves) did not belong to any category. Hence it was excluded from the coupon code. Hope that helps anyone else with this problem!!